# PyPyodbc returning Cursor Object after previously working with SQL query

Tags: python, html, sql, azure

Using the PyPyodbc import to connect to my Azure SQL datastore. Used it to retrieve data and it worked perfectly. Tried to add functionality where the Flask application added data to the SQL datastore and that's things went wrong.

```
`
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pypyodbc as odbc

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def base():
    return render_template('base.html')

@app.route('/index.html')
def index():
    connection_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Rest hidden for security'

    conn = odbc.connect(connection_string)

    sql = '''
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Hours] 
    '''
    cursor = conn.cursor().execute(sql)

    data = cursor

    print(data)
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)`
```

That used to return the 2 rows of data inside the SQL database but now just returns

`<pypyodbc.Cursor object at 0x000001E198749F10>`

Only difference in the next function is I used an INSERT INTO query rather than SELECT. Very confused how this has started happening.

Tried updating modules, changing the order of execute, cursor, etc. Checked the Azure SQL server for the data (It's still there). Completely stumped as to why this has suddenly started happening.

Comment: You got rid of `.fetchall()`. `data = cursor` is completely pointless, but you need `print(data.fetchall())` or `data = cursor.fetchall()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve data from SQL Azure, you should use:

```
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Instead of `data = cursor`. To print the data, you should use the code below:

```
data = cursor.fetchall()
for d in data:
    print(d)
```

Then, you will be able to get the data as mentioned below:

[image]

Complete code:

```
import pyodbc 

server = "<serverName>"
username = "<userName>"
password = "<password>"
database = "<database>"  

driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' 
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM student')

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Comment: The cursor itself should be iterable so there would be no need for `.fetchall()` if you're then going into a `for` loop